# C/C++ Compiler for Ubuntu like Dev-C++

Tags: gcc, compiler

Need a good c/c++ compiler for Ubuntu. I like coding or programming.

I used Dev-C++ on Windows. Is there any good compilers like Dev-C++?

I tried code::blocks ide but it seems a little buggy for me.

Comment: Are you looking for a compiler, or an IDE? Dev-C++ is an IDE that uses the mingw compiler. In either case @Nymeria answer is perfect. If you did mean IDE, though, please edit your question.

Comment: Geany is a light-weight IDE and gcc & g++ are c & c++ compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C++, you can install `g++`:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

For C, you can install `gcc`:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

If you need an IDE you can install NetBeans:

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

Comment: You could add info about `clang`.

Answer (score -1):

I like very much "Sublime text"

For SUBLIME text2 :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

For SUBLIME text3

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
 apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Comment: ST is a text editor, not an IDE and certainly not a compiler.

Comment: @oli you start war ?